# Power BI DirectQuery Report with automatic refresh

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a report in DirectQuery mode and hosted in Power BI Service. Besides the "refresh" button in the Menu bar, is there any way to enable the report to refresh automatically every 5 mins? For example, to insert a client side JavaScript to trigger the browser to refresh? Thank you.

Comment: Tiles refresh automatically every 15 minutes. If you feed your Power BI report with Stream Analytics you can have your report update in near real time.

Comment: Thank you Nick! I will do a research on Stream Analytics.